# Water not coming on after ball valve turned off

Tags: plumbing, water

We turned off the water supply going outside of the house during winter and we just turn that supply back on but there's no water coming out of the outside faucet. The lever connected to ball valve stem seems to be turning the stem properly and we pull the lever up and down a couple of times but not sure if ball is actually reopening properly. We turned on the drain valve while toggling the lever to see if any water come out, but there's no water coming out of the drain valve. Could something have been dislodged like mineral buildup that blocks the line or the ball valve is broken? Thanks.[image]

Comment: Is that picture from outside the house? If the water was turned off to prevent freeze damage, then the valve should not be outside. Check inside for another valve.

Comment: ball valves don't usually fail, there's not a lot to go wrong, especially at-rest.

Comment: Answer your own question for some up-vote points!

Answer (score 1):

You should feel some mild resistance turning the ball valve 90 degrees because the ball will rub snugly on the internal housing. internally, it's a ball with a hole right through the center, you align the hole with the piping to allow flow. So it's a basic piece of equipment. If you can see the inner stem turning along with the handle, then the valve should be working. Oftentimes the square keyed hole underneath the nut can get worn and slip. Otherwise I guess it's possible the stem and ball have somehow disconnected. You might be able to **feed** a long (semi rigid) thin **piece of wire down there** to see if it stops at the ball. this could eliminate the ball valve from the equation

Comment: Thanks RGW C.  I just found out there's another valve in front of that valve that was turn off.  Once I turned on both valves, water is coming out of the outside faucet.